# How to get rid of this problem ( On adding a nuget packages from VSCode it says terminated with exit code: 1.)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, nuget

## **When I trying to add *Nuget Packages* by *Nuget gallery* extension from *VS Code.* It doesn't install the *NuGet package.***

Executing task: dotnet add /home/[user]/Public/Projects/yogihosting.com/Identity/Identity/Identity.csproj package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore -v 5.0.6 -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json <

Determining projects to restore...
Writing /tmp/tmpIIHQRz.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore' into project '/home/[user]/Public/Projects/yogihosting.com/Identity/Identity/Identity.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for /home/[user]/Public/Projects/yogihosting.com/Identity/Identity/Identity.csproj...
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
error:   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
error:   The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot

Usage: NuGet.CommandLine.XPlat.dll package add [options]

Options:
-h|--help               Show help information
--force-english-output  Forces the application to run using an invariant, English-based culture.
--package               Id of the package to be added.
--version               Version of the package to be added.
-d|--dg-file            Path to the dependency graph file to be used to restore preview and compatibility check.
-p|--project            Path to the project file.
-f|--framework          Frameworks for which the package reference should be added.
-n|--no-restore         Do not perform restore preview and compatibility check. The added package reference will be unconditional.
-s|--source             Specifies NuGet package sources to use during the restore.
--package-directory     Directory to restore packages in.
--interactive           Allow the command to block and require manual action for operations like authentication.
--prerelease            Allows prerelease packages to be installed.
The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', 'dotnet add /home/[user]/Public/Projects/yogihosting.com/Identity/Identity/Identity.csproj package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore -v 5.0.6 -s [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'"](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%27%22) terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

### How can I get rid of this problem?

## https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json shows:#

[image]

**Note: I'm using Ubuntu.**

Comment: It looks like you can't communicate with the Nuget server, what happens if you open https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json on that same machine?

Comment: Hello DavidG. Other packages like `sqlite or sql server` install successfully. but not this [according to the question]. This question is updated providing the index.json file as image. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We may solve this issue by one of following process.**

- copy **project** to *another folder* or **create new project** to *another destination*.

> It may cause, our file or folder is corrupted.

- *Reinstalling* our **software(s)** like ***IDE*** or ***dotnet*** or ***both***.

> It may cause not to be installed correctly.

- The final is so funny. Re-install your **OS** and then **other softwares**.